# How to Apply a background effect on hover div without ovewriting the background

Tags: css, background, css-selectors, hover

I'm trying to apply a linear gradient layer over a div with a background-image setted, and a link and div with some content inside as childs.

I got it partially. But with a little unwanted behavior. You can check it the source code in [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/doL84hkn/)

```css
.IB-container {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 20px auto;

  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(6, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 0.5rem;
  grid-template-areas:
    "IB-area-1 IB-area-1 IB-area-2 IB-area-2 IB-area-2 IB-area-2"
    "IB-area-1 IB-area-1 IB-area-3 IB-area-3 IB-area-4 IB-area-4";
}

.IB-container > * {
  /* border-radius: 8px; */
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.IB-container .IB-area-1 {
  grid-area: IB-area-1;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.IB-container .IB-area-2 {
  grid-area: IB-area-2;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.IB-container .IB-area-3 {
  grid-area: IB-area-3;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.IB-container .IB-area-4 {
  grid-area: IB-area-4;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.IB-container .IB-image-link {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.IB-contenido {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
}

.IB-contenido .IB-imagen-1 {
  min-height: calc(100vh - 100px);
  background-image: url("https://images.pexels.com/photos/775687/pexels-photo-775687.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940");
}
.IB-contenido .IB-imagen-2 {
  background-image: url("https://images.pexels.com/photos/1144176/pexels-photo-1144176.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940");
}
.IB-contenido .IB-imagen-3 {
  background-image: url("https://images.pexels.com/photos/697313/pexels-photo-697313.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940");
}
.IB-contenido .IB-imagen-4 {
  background-image: url("https://images.pexels.com/photos/785405/pexels-photo-785405.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940");
}

.IB-contenido .IB-imagen-1,
.IB-contenido .IB-imagen-2,
.IB-contenido .IB-imagen-3,
.IB-contenido .IB-imagen-4 {
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.IB-contenido .IB-texto {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-align: center;
}

.IB-container .IB-h2 {
  position: relative;
  font-family: "Poiret One", cursive;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.IB-mb-3 {
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
}

.IB-text-button {
  position: relative;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  background: none;
  white-space: normal;
}

.IB-btn-small {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 12px;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
}

.IB-btn-line {
  color: #fff;
  transition: all 0.25s ease-in;
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 8px 20px 8px 24px;
  line-height: 18px;
}

div[class^="IB-area-"]:hover .IB-imagen {
  transition: all 0.8s ease;
  transform: scale(1.08);
}

.IB-imagen:hover:before {
  background: linear-gradient(to top, #000, transparent);
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 0.4;

}


.IB-text-button:hover {
  color: #acb1b7;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .IB-container {
    grid-template-areas:
      "IB-area-1 IB-area-1 IB-area-1 IB-area-1 IB-area-1 IB-area-1"
      "IB-area-2 IB-area-2 IB-area-2 IB-area-2 IB-area-2 IB-area-2"
      "IB-area-3 IB-area-3 IB-area-3 IB-area-3 IB-area-3 IB-area-3"
      "IB-area-4 IB-area-4 IB-area-4 IB-area-4 IB-area-4 IB-area-4";
  }

  .IB-container .IB-imagen-1,
  .IB-container .IB-imagen-2,
  .IB-container .IB-imagen-3,
  .IB-container .IB-imagen-4 {
    min-height: 250px;
    max-height: 250px;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poiret+One&display=swap"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="IB-container">
      <div class="IB-area-1">
        <a
          class="IB-image-link"
          href="https://google.com"
          title="titulo1"
          aria-label="titulo1"
        >
          <div class="IB-contenido">
            <div class="IB-imagen IB-imagen-1"></div>
            <div class="IB-texto">
              <div class="IB-h2 IB-mb-3">titulo 1</div>
              <div class="IB-text-button IB-btn-small IB-btn-line ">
                Ver Mas
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="IB-area-2">
        <a
          class="IB-image-link"
          href="https://google.com"
          title="titulo2"
          aria-label="titulo2"
        >
          <div class="IB-contenido">
            <div class="IB-imagen IB-imagen-2"></div>
            <div class="IB-texto">
              <div class="IB-h2 IB-mb-3">titulo 2</div>
              <div class="IB-text-button IB-btn-small IB-btn-line">Ver Mas</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="IB-area-3">
        <a
          class="IB-image-link"
          href="https://google.com"
          title="titulo3"
          aria-label="TITULO3"
        >
          <div class="IB-contenido">
            <div class="IB-imagen IB-imagen-3"></div>
            <div class="IB-texto">
              <div class="IB-h2 IB-mb-3">Titulo 3</div>
              <div class="IB-text-button IB-btn-small IB-btn-line ">
                Ver Mas
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="IB-area-4">
        <a
          class="IB-image-link"
          href="https://google.com"
          title="titulo4"
          aria-label="titulo4"
        >
          <div class="IB-contenido">
            <div class="IB-imagen IB-imagen-4"></div>
            <div class="IB-texto">
              <div class="IB-h2 IB-mb-3">Titulo 4</div>
              <div class="IB-text-button IB-btn-small IB-btn-line ">
                Ver Mas
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**The problem**
When I pointing over the parent div (`IB-area-N`) the hover pseudo-class works fine and perform the appropriate style changes, but when the pointer crosses over the child-div (IB-texto) the effect goes away.

I find that the deffect is between these two selectors.

```
div[class^="IB-area-"]:hover .IB-imagen {
  transition: all 0.8s ease;
  transform: scale(1.08);
}

.IB-imagen:hover:before {
  background: linear-gradient(to top, #000, transparent);
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 0.4;
}
```

Why not simply put the gradient in the first selector, along with the scale transform?...
Well not everything is so easy, when I tried the background image was overwritten :S

Can someone, please, give me a little light to this situation with these disturbing selectors?

Thank you a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply update this `.IB-imagen:hover:before` to `div[class^="IB-area-"]:hover .IB-imagen::before`

```css
.IB-container {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 20px auto;

  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(6, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 0.5rem;
  grid-template-areas:
    "IB-area-1 IB-area-1 IB-area-2 IB-area-2 IB-area-2 IB-area-2"
    "IB-area-1 IB-area-1 IB-area-3 IB-area-3 IB-area-4 IB-area-4";
}

.IB-container > * {
  /* border-radius: 8px; */
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.IB-container .IB-area-1 {
  grid-area: IB-area-1;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.IB-container .IB-area-2 {
  grid-area: IB-area-2;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.IB-container .IB-area-3 {
  grid-area: IB-area-3;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.IB-container .IB-area-4 {
  grid-area: IB-area-4;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.IB-container .IB-image-link {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.IB-contenido {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
}

.IB-contenido .IB-imagen-1 {
  min-height: calc(100vh - 100px);
  background-image: url("https://images.pexels.com/photos/775687/pexels-photo-775687.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940");
}
.IB-contenido .IB-imagen-2 {
  background-image: url("https://images.pexels.com/photos/1144176/pexels-photo-1144176.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940");
}
.IB-contenido .IB-imagen-3 {
  background-image: url("https://images.pexels.com/photos/697313/pexels-photo-697313.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940");
}
.IB-contenido .IB-imagen-4 {
  background-image: url("https://images.pexels.com/photos/785405/pexels-photo-785405.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940");
}

.IB-contenido .IB-imagen-1,
.IB-contenido .IB-imagen-2,
.IB-contenido .IB-imagen-3,
.IB-contenido .IB-imagen-4 {
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.IB-contenido .IB-texto {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-align: center;
}

.IB-container .IB-h2 {
  position: relative;
  font-family: "Poiret One", cursive;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.IB-mb-3 {
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
}

.IB-text-button {
  position: relative;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  background: none;
  white-space: normal;
}

.IB-btn-small {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 12px;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
}

.IB-btn-line {
  color: #fff;
  transition: all 0.25s ease-in;
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 8px 20px 8px 24px;
  line-height: 18px;
}

div[class^="IB-area-"]:hover .IB-imagen {
  transition: all 0.8s ease;
  transform: scale(1.08);
}

div[class^="IB-area-"]:hover .IB-imagen::before {
  background: linear-gradient(to top, #000, transparent);
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 0.4;

}


.IB-text-button:hover {
  color: #acb1b7;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .IB-container {
    grid-template-areas:
      "IB-area-1 IB-area-1 IB-area-1 IB-area-1 IB-area-1 IB-area-1"
      "IB-area-2 IB-area-2 IB-area-2 IB-area-2 IB-area-2 IB-area-2"
      "IB-area-3 IB-area-3 IB-area-3 IB-area-3 IB-area-3 IB-area-3"
      "IB-area-4 IB-area-4 IB-area-4 IB-area-4 IB-area-4 IB-area-4";
  }

  .IB-container .IB-imagen-1,
  .IB-container .IB-imagen-2,
  .IB-container .IB-imagen-3,
  .IB-container .IB-imagen-4 {
    min-height: 250px;
    max-height: 250px;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poiret+One&display=swap"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="IB-container">
      <div class="IB-area-1">
        <a
          class="IB-image-link"
          href="https://google.com"
          title="titulo1"
          aria-label="titulo1"
        >
          <div class="IB-contenido">
            <div class="IB-imagen IB-imagen-1"></div>
            <div class="IB-texto">
              <div class="IB-h2 IB-mb-3">titulo 1</div>
              <div class="IB-text-button IB-btn-small IB-btn-line ">
                Ver Mas
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="IB-area-2">
        <a
          class="IB-image-link"
          href="https://google.com"
          title="titulo2"
          aria-label="titulo2"
        >
          <div class="IB-contenido">
            <div class="IB-imagen IB-imagen-2"></div>
            <div class="IB-texto">
              <div class="IB-h2 IB-mb-3">titulo 2</div>
              <div class="IB-text-button IB-btn-small IB-btn-line">Ver Mas</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="IB-area-3">
        <a
          class="IB-image-link"
          href="https://google.com"
          title="titulo3"
          aria-label="TITULO3"
        >
          <div class="IB-contenido">
            <div class="IB-imagen IB-imagen-3"></div>
            <div class="IB-texto">
              <div class="IB-h2 IB-mb-3">Titulo 3</div>
              <div class="IB-text-button IB-btn-small IB-btn-line ">
                Ver Mas
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="IB-area-4">
        <a
          class="IB-image-link"
          href="https://google.com"
          title="titulo4"
          aria-label="titulo4"
        >
          <div class="IB-contenido">
            <div class="IB-imagen IB-imagen-4"></div>
            <div class="IB-texto">
              <div class="IB-h2 IB-mb-3">Titulo 4</div>
              <div class="IB-text-button IB-btn-small IB-btn-line ">
                Ver Mas
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Temani! thank you so much! It works and also I understood a little bit more about selectors 
...So far that I traveled to look for, and the solution was always there, so close...